# Binding click to a repeated div ID

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a `div` popup gallery type thing. But I'm having an issue with my approach.

I have a few linked thumbnail images, which link to the large image.
Each of these images looks like so

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="galImage">
<img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/3/0/3/3030/rogan-josh-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
<br />
<a href="www.yahoo.com" id="galImage">
<img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/2/9/8/2986/italian-herbs-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
```

As you can see, each  has the same id of "galImage". I didnt want to create a separate ID for each as sometimes there might be 2 image and sometimes there might be 20. So just thought simply checking to see if #galImage get's clicked i'd run some jquery.

My issue is, that only the very first occurence of #galImage triggers the jquery, every other instance fails.

Here's a JSfiddle with the above example. http://jsfiddle.net/MH6eJ/1/
Click image 1, it works. But image 2 fails.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), your `id` has do be unique in the page. If you want to have more HTML elements with that style (for exapmle), use `class`.

> ```
> id = name [CS]:
> ```
>
> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.
>
> ```
> class = cdata-list [CS]:
> ```
>
> This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space characters.

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="galImage">
<img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/3/0/3/3030/rogan-josh-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
<br />
<a href="www.yahoo.com" class="galImage">
<img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/2/9/8/2986/italian-herbs-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
```

Then when you select with jQuery that class you use `$(".galImage")`.

```
$('.galImage').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MH6eJ/2/).

Comment: Wonderful, didnt realize there was a difference between classes and id's. Good stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ID, repeating ID's isn't a good idea.

Using classes you solve your problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MH6eJ/1/)

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="galImage">
<img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/3/0/3/3030/rogan-josh-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
    <br />
<a href="www.yahoo.com" class="galImage">
<img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/2/9/8/2986/italian-herbs-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>

$('.galImage').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All IDs must be unique. If you wish to repeat an ID, you should use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

An element's Id must be unique. So you can't have two a tags with same ids.

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="galImage">
<img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/3/0/3/3030/rogan-josh-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
    <br />
<a href="www.yahoo.com" class="galImage">
<img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/2/9/8/2986/italian-herbs-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.galImage').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use classes instead as IDs must be unique.

E.g

```
<a href="www.google.com" id="Google" class="galImage">
   <img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/3/0/3/3030/rogan-josh-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
<br />
<a href="www.yahoo.com" id="Yahoo" class="galImage">
   <img src="http://www.savoryspiceshop.com/content/mercury_modules/cart/items/2/9/8/2986/italian-herbs-salt-free-thumbnail-fw232.jpg">
</a>
```

and your jQuery would be

```
$('.galImage').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).attr("href"));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids are supposed to be unique.  You can use a classes instead of IDs and bind to the class name.

In your fiddle add `class=galImage` to each Href and then in your jQuery binding, use `.galImage` instead of `#galImage`.  jQuery should then bind to all elements with class name of `galImage`

Answer (score 0):

When we have to attach an event/style with multiple elements, we have to use classes. Id means a unique value for each element.