# Getting the value of a hidden field in <td> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table data which is generated dynamically via a loop. The td contains a hidden field. below is the code for the same:

```html
<td class="gridtd" id = "r<%=RowNumber%>c<%=ColumnNumber%>">
<input id="hiddendata" type="hidden" value="<%: item.Key%>"/>
</td>
```

I need to extract the value of the hidden field based on the td selected using jQuery. Please help me get the correct jquery code.

Comment: `$('#hiddendata').val();`

Comment: But there are multiple hiddendata as the loop is creating multiple td. So how will jQuery know which is the correct hidden id corresponding to the td selected.

Comment: For adequate elements' selecting their IDs **must** be unique. It is a bad style to use multiple same IDs. But in this situation you can use Ionică Bizău, P5Coder and user3168736 answers.

Comment: what if my hidden field id is also a variable to the effect of 
id=hdnr<%=RowNumber%>c<%=ColumnNumber%>
How will I then be able to get the value of the hidden field?

Comment: Then you can either select element by its ID or use, for example, mentioned `$('.gridtd').click(function() { console.log($(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val()); });`

Comment: @DebashisPaul Don't forget to press `✔` button on the correct answer. If there is no correct answer, leave comments what do you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select your input and take the value (`val()`):

```
$("#hiddendata").val();
```

If you want to take all hidden input values:

```
$("input[type='hidden']").each(function () {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Note that the [element ids must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15044597/1420197).

> I need to extract the value of the hidden field based on the td selected using jQuery.

If by *select* you mean, *click*, you can simply pass `this` when getting the value:

```
$("td").on("click", function () {
   console.log(
     $("[type='hidden']", this).val()
   );
});
```

For your general knowledge, if you do `$("#hiddendata", this).val();` inside of the click handler, it will return the correct value (even having multiple ids with the same value).

But definitely, the ids must be unique.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was able to get the value of all the hidden fields.  I will now process the results as required.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
  $('#hiddendata').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').click(
    function(event)
    {
      $(event.target).find('#hiddendata').val();
    }
);
```

It ll give the hiddendata value based on td selection

Answer (score 0):

This will give the value of the hidden field for the selected `td`.

```
$('.gridtd').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('input').val());
});
```

Comment: Same understanding as mine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.gridtd').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('input[type=hidden]').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.gridtd').each(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    var hiddenval = $('#'+currentId).find('input[type=hidden]').val();
    alert(hiddenval);
})
```