# Unexpected string error jquery

Tags: jquery

I am targeting dynamic `div`s for that I made a code

```
if ($("#" + selector_name "#" + name + add_count).size() == 0) {
    var p = "<div id = '" + name + add_count + "' class='progressbar' data-perc='0'><div class='bar'><span></span></div><div class='label-up'><span></span></div><div class='mi-avtr-cnt'></div><div class='clear'></div></div>"; 
    $(".mitxt").append(p);  
}
```

How can I target `div`s dynamically . The problem is with line  `"#" + selector_name "#" + name + add_count`

Comment: What are `selector_name`, `name` and `add_count`? You should provide more context! Also, you are missing `+` between  `selector_name "#"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error because a `+` is missing:

```
if ($("#" + selector_name + "#" + name + add_count).size() == 0) { ... }
                          ^ -- This was missing
```

Also note that ids are supposed to be unique in document, so a div can only have one id (that is also unique). You may want to do `$("#" + selector_name + ",#" + name + add_count)` (selecting two elements with different ids).

- [Ids must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15044597/1420197)

Comment: Thanks a lot for noticing it . :)

Answer (score 0):

`"#" + selector_name "#" + name + add_count` this selector is not a valid selector(And this is a syntax error).
A valid id selector is `'#' + your_element_id`

use `'#' + name + add_count` as selector should solve your problem

Comment: That's not really a selector, that's an error-prone _expression_.